# Models in viewmodel gave me null error while they are'nt null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm developing a `Asp.net MVC 5` webApplication with `Razor Engine`. I have a `layout` that shows some data from this models: (Footers , FooterMenus , SocialNetworks) from db , and I have a view named `register.cshtml` that shows a Form page to add user . I want to add `layout` to `register.cshtml` but I don't know how write a ViewModel for this . I wrote these codes below but `Footers , FooterMenu , SocialNetworks` shows anything  because of this code in `RegisterVM`:

```
 public RegisterVM()
{
    //Initialize these properties to empty list.
    this.Footers = new List<Footer>();
    this.FooterMenus = new List<FooterMenu>();
    this.SocialNetworks = new List<SocialNetwork>();
    this.Users = new List<User>();
}
```

If I remove this code , it gave me an compiler error and says `models are null`. How should I solve these ?!
I'm working for 3 days on this error :(

RegisterVM.cs

```
public class RegisterVM
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
    public string UserPassWord { get; set; }
    public string UserCellPhone { get; set; }
    public string UserTell { get; set; }
    public string UserImage { get; set; }
    public string UserAddress { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> UserStatus { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UserBirthDate { get; set; }
    public string UserGender { get; set; }

    public List<SocialNetwork> SocialNetworks { get; set; }
    public List<Footer> Footers { get; set; }
    public List<FooterMenu> FooterMenus { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }

    public RegisterVM()
    {
        //Initialize these properties to empty list.
        this.Footers = new List<Footer>();
        this.FooterMenus = new List<FooterMenu>();
        this.SocialNetworks = new List<SocialNetwork>();
        this.Users = new List<User>();
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        RegisterVM vm = new RegisterVM();
        vm.UserAddress = "";
        vm.UserBirthDate = DateTime.Now;
        vm.UserCellPhone = "";
        vm.UserEmail = "";
        vm.UserFirstName = "";
        vm.UserGender = "";
        vm.UserID = 1;
        vm.UserImage = "";
        vm.UserLastName = "";
        vm.UserPassWord = "";
        vm.UserStatus = 1;
        vm.UserTell = "";
        return View(vm);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(User user)
    {
        UserRepositories bluser = new UserRepositories();
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(bluser.Add(user))
            {
                //Succsess
            }
            else
            {
                //un Succsess
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //error 
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**RegisterLayout.cshtml**

```
@model NP1.ViewModels.RegisterVM
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>

@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@RenderSection("styles", false)


 </head>
  <body style="width: 100% !important; padding: 0px; overflow-x: hidden;">
//menu is here //
<div>
    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", false)
  </div>

 <div>
    <footer class="footer text-center FooterFont hidden-xs" style="bottom: 0;overflow:hidden; text-align: center; color: GrayText; clear: both; margin-bottom: -30px; background-color: #191919 !important; padding-top: 20px;">
        <div class=" text-center" style="background-color:#191919 !important; padding-bottom:20px;width:100%;text-align:center;">

            <ul style="text-align: center; background-color: #191919; list-style-type: none; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;" class="list-group col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Footers)
                    {
                        <ul style="text-align: center; list-style-type: none; background-color: #191919;">
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <a class="aFooter" href="@item.FooterLink">
                                    <span>@item.FooterName</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    }
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul style="border-right: 1px graytext solid; border-left: 1px graytext solid; text-align: center; list-style-type: none; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;background-color:#191919;" class="list-group col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-4">


                <li class="list-group-item">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.FooterMenus)
                    {
                        <ul style="text-align:center;list-style-type:none;">
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <a class="aFooter" href="@item.FooterMenuLink">
                                    <span>@item.FooterMenuName</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    }
                </li>

            </ul>

            <ul style="text-align: center; list-style-type: none; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;" class="list-group col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-4">

                <li class="list-group-item">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.SocialNetworks)
                    {
                        <ul style="text-align:center;list-style-type:none;padding-top:15px;">
                            <li>
                                <a class="aFooter" href="@item.SocialLink">
                                    <img class="img-responsive center-block socialIcon" src="@Url.Content(item.SocialIcon.ToString())" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    }
                </li>
            </ul>


        </div>
    </footer>


    <footer class="footer text-center FooterFont visible-xs" style="bottom: 0;overflow:hidden; text-align: center; color: GrayText; clear: both; margin-bottom: -30px; background-color: #191919 !important; padding-top: 20px;">
        <div class=" text-center" style="background-color:#191919 !important; padding-bottom:20px;width:100%;text-align:center;">

            <ul style="text-align: center; list-style-type: none; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;" class="list-group col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Footers)
                    {
                        <ul style="text-align:center;list-style-type:none;">
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <a class="aFooter" href="@item.FooterLink">
                                    <span>@item.FooterName</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    }
                </li>
            </ul>



            <ul style=" text-align: center; list-style-type: none; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;" class="list-group col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6 col-sm-4">


                <li class="list-group-item">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.FooterMenus)
                    {
                        <ul style="text-align:center;list-style-type:none;">
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <a class="aFooter" href="@item.FooterMenuLink">
                                    <span>@item.FooterMenuName</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    }
                </li>

            </ul>



            <ul style="text-align: center; list-style-type: none;  vertical-align: top;">

                <li>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.SocialNetworks)
                    {
                        <ul class="list-inline" style="text-align:center;list-style-type:none;">
                            <li class="col-xs-3">
                                <a style="padding:3px;" class="aFooter" href="@item.SocialLink">
                                    <img class="img-responsive center-block socialIcon" src="@Url.Content(item.SocialIcon.ToString())" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    }
                </li>
            </ul>


        </div>
    </footer>

</div>
```

**Register.cshtml**

```
@model NP1.ViewModels.RegisterVM

 @{
ViewBag.Title = "register";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_RegisterLayout.cshtml";
 }

  @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
  {
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserEmail, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserEmail)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserEmail)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserFirstName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserFirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserFirstName)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserLastName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserLastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserLastName)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserPassWord, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserPassWord)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserPassWord)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserCellPhone, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserCellPhone)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserCellPhone)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserTell, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserTell)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserTell)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserImage, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserImage)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserImage)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserAddress, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserAddress)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserAddress)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserBirthDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserBirthDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserBirthDate)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserGender, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserGender)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserGender)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  }

 <div>
   @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: What is the model data type of layout?

Comment: It's `RegisterVM`  @user1672994

Comment: Does the layout specifics various partial view for footer, footerlinks and Social networks and each partial view is bind to specific model (`Footer`, `FooterLinks` and `SocalNetworks`)?

Comment: No , I didn't use partial view I just show they with foreach in ul list and I have one ViewModel (RegisterVm) for all of them @user1672994

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C#6 or higher you can use default properties

```
//default properties in C#6    
public class RegisterVM
{

public int UserID { get; set; } =1;
public string UserEmail { get; set; } ="";
public string UserFirstName { get; set; } ="";
public string UserLastName { get; set; } ="";
public string UserPassWord { get; set; } ="";
public string UserCellPhone { get; set; } ="";
public string UserTell { get; set; } ="";
public string UserImage { get; set; } ="";
public string UserAddress { get; set; } ="";
public Nullable<byte> UserStatus { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> UserBirthDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
public string UserGender { get; set; } ="";


public List<SocialNetwork> SocialNetworks { get; set; }
public List<Footer> Footers { get; set; }
public List<FooterMenu> FooterMenus { get; set; }
public List<User> Users { get; set; }

    public RegisterVM()
    {

        this.Footers = new List<Footer>();
        this.FooterMenus = new List<FooterMenu>();
        this.SocialNetworks = new List<SocialNetwork>();
        this.Users = new List<User>();
    }
}
```

However the main issue is you are not mapping the viewmodel to the database model.

You are also receiving your database model in the post instead of the viewwmodel.

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    RegisterVM vm = new RegisterVM();
    return View(vm);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterVM vm)
{


    UserRepositories bluser = new UserRepositories();

    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.Id=vm.UserID;
        user.FirstName=vm.UserFirstName;            
        user.UserLastName=vm.UserLastName;   
        //etc

        if(bluser.Add(user))
        {
            //Succsess
        }
        else
        {
            //un Succsess
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //error 
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thank you dear , but it's the same and data didn't show .

Comment: Post your view/cshmtl

Comment: Your post code public ActionResult Register(User user) needs to read public ActionResult Register(RegisterVM vm)

Comment: I added this before , but result didn't show any change :(